# Dart DateTime broken?

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart, datetimepicker

I use Flutter's calendar to pick a date in my app, but I make sure to restrict it to the current month only. I do so by setting:

1. firstDate: beginningOfMonth (eg, June 1st, 2019,
2. lastDate: beginningOfNextMonth (eg, July 1st, 2019),
3. initialdate: DateTime.now()

Now that it's the end of the month (June 30th at the time of writing), I'm getting an AssertionError saying that `initialDate must be on or before lastDate`. So I printed (the best debugger!) my dates and I got:

1. `initialDate: 2019-06-30 20:07:25`
2. `endOfMonth: 2019-07-01 00:00:00`

Just like I expected. But when I compare the two, I get `initialDate.isBefore (endOfMonth) == false)`.

Is this just some human-error on my part, or do I have to contact the Flutter team?

Answer (score 4):

Wow, OK, talk about race condition. At the time of posting, I'm at GMT-4, and it's 8:30. And I was using `DateTime.utc`. So `DateTime.now()` would show as June 30th, 8:30pm, and UTC time would try to adjust to my time-zone, and ended up after midnight, which meant it was technically a whole different day. Swapped out `DateTime.utc` for `DateTime()` and the problem was solved!

Comment: Wow, I just spent like 2 hours on a very similar issue - comparing DateTime.utc, to my Datetime.now and getting unexpected results.... it all makes sense after reading this. Thanks for posting this!